# Weighted Mahalanobis or ZCA whitening and de-whitening

Tags: pca, data-transformation

Assume I have a centered $n \times d$ matrix $X$ with $n$ data points in $d$ dimensions. If I wish to transform it to $Y$ such that

1. $Y$ has identity covariance
2. $\|X -  Y \|^2$ is minimized

According to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117427/what-is-the-difference-between-zca-whitening-and-pca-whitening) and section 6.1 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00809.pdf), I should use ZCA transformation.  Point #2 can be rephrased as minimizing the quantity $c$ subject to $Y$ having identity covariance

$c=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d {\left( x_{ij} - y_{ij} \right) }^2$

The procedure can be 'reversed': Given $Y$ is whitened it can be transformed by the inverse of ZCA to have any arbitrary covariance, $R$, creating matrix $Z$, which minimizes $\|Y -  Z \|^2$. (However, I am unsure if that also minimize $\|X -  Z \|^2$ if able to transform $X$ to $Z$ directly in one step.)

The main question I have is how to use ZCA in a slightly generalized fashion. The optimization problem I needed to solve is equivalent to transforming $X$ into $Z$ but subject to

1. $Z$ has given covariance $R$
2. $c^*=\|X -  Z \|_W^2$ is minimized

Where it is a weighted least squares sum,

$c^*=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{{\left( x_{ij} - z_{ij} \right) }^2}{s_{ij}}$

I see how to do the two-step procedure above to get $Z$ with covariance $R$, first from whitened $Y$, but unsure if that minimizes $\|X -  Z \|^2$. The weighted least squares criteria is not met though.

(I technically have a more difficult problem: $X$ has mean $u_x$, and wish $Z$ to have mean $u_z$ and covariance $R$ given the weighted least squares sum minimized; I believe the means do not matter in unweighted least squares - however, they may in this case as not only weighted but in my problem they depend on $x_{ij}$ individually $r_{ij}=2x_{ij}(1-x_{ij})$)

Comment: Weighted problems like that rarely have closed form solution in terms of SVD (e.g. http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~zamir/documents/lower.pdf), so most likely you will need to implement some optimization scheme.