# What could be a good metric for rotation/translation-invariant image similarities?

Tags: image-processing, procrustes-analysis

An acquaintance posted an interesting image processing question. In the image below, we can tell that (a) and (c) are similar, whereas (b) is different. If we use (a) as a template and want to have a single-number similarity measure that give us a high value between (a) and (c) and a low value between (a) and (b), what should we use? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Procrustes rotation will superimpose a an c the way they are maximally aligned with each other. Then usual euclidean distance will be almost zero if the two images are indeed very similar. This operation, however, implies that we know which point in one image which point in the other image corresponds to, and, of course, the number of points must be the same.

Comment: In other words, if you take a copy of an image, rotate it, scale it, shift it, then procrustes will "undo" these operations done on the copy and will demonstrate that the two images were identical.

Comment: This topic (including procrustes) is much related to ZCA whitening. See e.g. excellent http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117463/3277 and other threads.

Comment: Thank you @ttnphns! Yet to experiment but will try things out this PM :)